# jQuery - show/hide multiple modals

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I open either `.modal` using an `id` for each `.button` and a `data-id` for each modal?

If either `.modal` is open and I click the other `.button`, I want the modals to toggle (where the open one closes and the closed one opens).

```js
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  $('.modal').toggleClass('active');
});
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if (($(".modal").hasClass("active")) && (!$(".modal, .modal *, .button").is(e.target))) {
    $(".modal").toggleClass("active");
  }
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.modal').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.button {
  height: 30px;
}

.header {
  height: 15px;
  background: #eee;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 72px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 6;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: top right;
  transition: 0.15s;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 1.5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.modal:after {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background: #eee;
  top: -6px;
  right: 8px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5);
  transition: 0.15s;
}

.modal.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.modal.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.dignitasteam.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/3050613-inline-i-2-googles-new-logo-copy.png" class="button" id="google" />
<img src="https://www.arabianbusiness.com/sites/default/files/styles/full_img/public/images/2017/01/17/apple-logo-rainbow.jpg" class="button" id="apple" />
<div class="modal" data-id="google">
  <div class="header">Google</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal" data-id="apple">
  <div class="header">Google</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the id of the button `.prop('id')` to the data-id of the modal `.data('id')` and toggle the `.active` class based on the equality of the values. You can accurately toggle the class by looping through the modals using `$(.modal).each` and utilizing the state parameter of the `.toggleClass()` function to hide all that don't match the button id and show the one that does match.

Your sample code seems to have two issues:

- a click on the html toggles the `.active` class on all modals so I switched that to `removeClass`.
- Both modals say Google so I switched the apple modal to say Apple.

```js
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  const id = $(this).prop('id');
  $('.modal').each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active', $(this).data('id') == id);
  });
});
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if (($(".modal").hasClass("active")) && (!$(".modal, .modal *, .button").is(e.target))) {
    $(".modal").removeClass("active");
  }
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.modal').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.button {
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header {
  height: 15px;
  background: #eee;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 72px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 6;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: top right;
  transition: 0.15s;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 1.5px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.modal:after {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background: #eee;
  top: -6px;
  right: 8px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5);
  transition: 0.15s;
}

.modal.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.modal.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.dignitasteam.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/3050613-inline-i-2-googles-new-logo-copy.png" class="button" id="google" />
<img src="https://www.arabianbusiness.com/sites/default/files/styles/full_img/public/images/2017/01/17/apple-logo-rainbow.jpg" class="button" id="apple" />
<div class="modal" data-id="google">
  <div class="header">Google</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal" data-id="apple">
  <div class="header">Apple</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to change `data-id` to `id` and call it differently:

```
<div class="modal" id="googleModal">
  <div class="header">Google</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="appleModal">
  <div class="header">Apple</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      First</li>
    <li>
      Second</li>
    <li>
      Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then in your script just get the id of your image and add class:

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'google'){ 
       $('#googleModal').toggleClass('active'); 
       $('#appleModal').removeClass('active'); } 
    else if($(this).attr('id') == 'apple'){ 
       $('#appleModal').toggleClass('active'); 
       $('#googleModal').removeClass('active'); } 
});
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/605111/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this.

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    var b_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('.modal').each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("active"))
            $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
    $("[data-id='"+b_id+"']").toggleClass('active');
});

$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if (($(".modal").hasClass("active")) && (!$(".modal, .modal *, .button").is(e.target))) {
        $(".modal").removeClass("active");
    }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.modal').removeClass('active');
});
```